# Supressing specific error throws from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, stderr

I am using a library that throws a reasonable error when called upen and completes the desired action such that my outputs are as expected. However, as other people will use the script, I think the error might be misleading since it's not a problem. I have supressed it using the following command within the script:

```
exec 2> /dev/null
```

The problem is that this throws *all* of the errors to the null directory, thus not printing any other error that might occur.

What I am looking for is a command that can remove errors raised by specific libraries from showing up on the console, allowing others to appear naturally.

Comment: What libraries, and in what language?

Answer (score 1):

> What I am looking for is a command that can remove errors raised by specific libraries from showing up on the console, allowing others to appear naturally.

You can pass the logging options to the callee command via a logging configuration document. In there you the caller would be deciding which of the specific libraries' logging lines would be trashed away, and which ones would be dumped to stderr.

To me this is just a common scenario of logging. Most popular Python and Java logging libraries allow this.

Comment: Which libraries? Have an example of such a logging configuration document? And, most importantly, what if the program in question doesn't use such a logging library? There doesn't seem to be anything in the question indicating what sort of a program it is.

Comment: Most system syslog facilities can do such things, too.